# Applet not working

Tags: java, applet, java-7, classnotfoundexception, java-6

I have Websphere 8.5.5.4 running on JRE 1.7.0. I have a applet that works on JRE -1.6. All client machines are running JRE 1.5.0_15. Logging and Tracing are enabled and the console to show. IE 8 is the client browsers.

1. When I access the webpage, the applet fails to load. There is not even an error icon or anything, console does not open. When I go to http server log path and check for errors, there is an entry in the file when I access the webpage, however no error.
2. Applet is working in JRE 1.6.0_07 version.
3. Applet is not working in JRE 1.5.0_15 version.
4. Is there any relation between the client JRE version and the JRE version running on the Server?
5. Any specific configuration needs to be added for WAS 8.5.4

Getting the below error while loading with JRE 1.5.0_15

```
Java Plug-in 1.5.0_15
Using JRE version 1.5.0_15 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\
----------------------------------------------------
load: class TestApplet.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestApplet.class
                at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
                at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
                at sun.plugin.AppletViewer.createApplet(Unknown Source)
                at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
                at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
basic: Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestApplet.class
```

Summarizing, applet does not work in JRE 1.5.0_15 version and working only in  JRE 1.6.0_07  version. I expect it should work in JRE 1.5.0_15 version.

Thank you

Comment: Java 5 is outdated since many years. Why you would like to use it?

Comment: There is no relation between the client JRE and the Server JRE. Moreover, you can download the applet to a local file and test if it works instead of download it from the Server.

Comment: My guess is that you have to compile the applet with a Java 1.5 compiler for it to run on Java 1.5.  Applets are obsolete and may not run on current browsers.

Comment: Well, compilers have the `-target` option… But I’m shuddering reading “Applet” and these outdated version numbers, I mean even never-updated within their particular major version, JREs, rembering all the security issues of the last ten years…